# Doing a checkout via API?

Tags: 8, commerce

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to do a checkout via API for Drupal commerce 2.
In Drupal 7 there was a module Commerce Services Resources.

I found some posts, but they don't answer my question:

- [Can I connect via REST services with a mobile app I will develop?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272440/can-i-connect-via-rest-services-with-a-mobile-app-i-will-develop/272446#272446)
- [Is there any module for Restful API in drupal 7 with commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177745/is-there-any-module-for-restful-api-in-drupal-7-with-commerce)

I also found a not finished / maintained repository containing some web apis doing similar stuff, https://github.com/solody/commerce_checkout_api

Comment: What do you needed out of an API here? A "checkout" in Commerce 2.x essentially requires populating an order object and updating its status to placed. Are you looking for more granular APIs for various parts of the form itself? e.g. do you need a Commerce 2.x API to validate a coupon? format an address form? etc.

Comment: I want to develop a single page application which is using the different APIs from searching products over creating an order object to adding payments.

Comment: @CSchulz Have you found a way?